# Using a passed string as part of a resource name

Tags: .net, vb.net

I find myself writing a function like this:

```
Public Shared Function RiskBarTitle(ByVal passedWord As String) As String
Dim returnText As String = ""

Try
Select Case passedWord.ToLower
 Case "tobacco"
  returnText = My.Resources.rptPfr9Common.wTobacco     
Case "alcohol"
  returnText = My.Resources.rptPfr9Common.wAlcohol
 Case Else
  returnText = "Oops, no graph title available."
End Select
...
```

Rather then repeating the case statement is there some way to use the passed variable 'passedWord' to complete the resource name so that it can be used directly? So it would look something like:

```
My.Resources.rptPfr9Common.passedWord
```

I have searched widely but evidently I do not know how to describe it sufficiently to find a solution.

Thanks,

Matthew

Comment: I can't test it right now, have you tried playing with the resource manager? something like: My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("[name]")

Answer (score 0):

As the_lotus mentionned above, this works (in C#)

```
 MessageBox.Show(ResFile.ResourceManager.GetObject("resourceName").ToString());
```

Sorry I don't have VB installed but you should easily find your way to adapt this in VB.

Answer (score 0):

Mathew, does this do the trick for you:

```
My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("nameOfResource")
```

Comment: This approach, suggested by you and  @Francis, returns 'nothing.' The resource file I am trying to access is different from the one returned by 'ResourceManager'. I tried the same format with 'My.Resources.rptPfr9Common.GetObject("objectresource")'  This returned the error "'getobject' is not a member of 'SbirtReportsClassLib.My.Resources.rptPfr9Common'".